# How to make a piezo speaker louder with 5V?

Tags: arduino, audio, wave, square

I have connected a tiny piezo pc speaker (https://sktechworks.ca/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Speaker.jpg) to an arduino and used to tone command to play a simple melody in repeat (square wave only since I didn't use a DAC).
But the speaker is very quiet. I have used a speaker like the green one here: [image]

but it is not siginifcantly louder (I need a piezo either way).
I then tried to just connect it to 2 digital ports and just inverted low and high between them, which did make it louder, just not enough.

So here my question, with the same voltage is there a way to produce a louder sound? 
I just need a sound  can clearly hear through a few walls.
Because I have a usb speaker (which is 5V) and that one is signifcantly louder.

Comment: What matters is not the speaker/sounder you're using but that the **output** of the module you take the output from is capable of driving a speaker. If it is not explicitly stated that that output can drive a speaker (for example it is named: SPK+ / SPK-) then probably it cannot drive a speaker, it might be a "line" level output. Then you need an **audio power amplifier** in between. Something like a module based on the LM386 chip.

Comment: I thought a speakers resitance changed with the one applied to it? Menaing the more amps the louder it gets?

Comment: also don't I need an external powersource for an audio amplifier?

Comment: First, is that actually a piezo and not a magnetic speaker?.  Unfortunately Bimpelrekkie's claim is quite incorrect - what you need to drive a small piezo vs a magnetic speaker is quite different.  So first you must figure out what you have.  Does it have a low resistance when measured out of circuit with a speaker?  If so it is magnetic.  In contrast a piezo looks like a capacitor and will be seen as an open circuit by an ohm meter.

Comment: And @ChrisStratton also doesn't know what he's talking about, many speaker boxes use piezo tweeters which are driven by the same power amplifier as the other (magnetic) speakers in the same box. What Chris means is that to drive a small piezo as loud as possible, it needs to be part of an oscillator circuit. This is for example used in smoke alarms. But this kind of configuration isn't very suitable to reproduce a melody like OP wants. A small piezo speaker on a standard PA will work, it might not be loud enough though. Then use a magnetic speaker.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie continuous mix up the technical facts.  Piezo and magnetic speakers are **drastically different loads**, and while there are ways in which piezo tweeters can be used in hybrid systems, they are not a natural match - in fact they often require a series resistor.  At a basic level, a magnetic speaker looks like a short circuit at DC, while a piezo is an open circuit at DC but looks like a short circuit to fast transitions, which means that it can readily overheat cheaper class D amplifiers. And with a square wave source, there's little reason to use an inefficient linear amplifier.

Comment: To drive a piezo element loudly with a square wave source, what you want it s moderately high voltage switch capable of working into substantial capacitance (though for moderate volumes, an MCU output or two driven in opposite phase works just fine).  While "alerter" type system will sometimes resonate the piezo element with an inductor, that only works for a narrower frequency range than may be implied by a "melody".

Comment: So basicly what I get from this:  

- Theres no way to get louder sound without either an amplifier chip or an oscillator 
- which means I need an external power source  
- If I just wan't a loud as fuck alarm without any melody I need an oscillator chip and an external power source with more amps  
- if I wan't a loud song to be played I need an amplifier chip and an external power source (and a DAC?)   (sorry newlines are broken)

Comment: If you just want a loud and annoying alert sound, modify a dollar store / pound shop reed switch alarm which resonates the piezo and works off maybe 4.5v from three coin cells.  If you want loud music, use a mid-range magnetic speaker with a class D amplifier and a DAC.  If you want typical MCU project bleeps and bloops in the same room, drive a piezo directly from a GPIO.  While if you want to use a small magnetic speaker for same-room square wave sounds, use a transistor to amplify current and be careful to limit the DC component via either a series capacitor or in your pattern of usage.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into all of these.

Answer (score -1):

use an impedance matching transformer with largest turns ratio

such as [these](https://www.murata.com/en-sg/products/matching/stama)

Comment: Could you expand this answer?